# How can I receive data of an external API with Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I try to create an chrome extension who works with an another API. So my content script get the data in DOM and ask the API the result (in background.js)

So, I send a message from `contentscript.js` to `background.js` and I wait the response of my API since `sendResponse`. But, I have a problem the response is always `undefined` because `contentscript.js` receive the response except I don't yet send the response.

contentscript.js :

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "new", data: {/* ... */}}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

background.js :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, _, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.type == "new") {

        execute(msg.data).then(function (response) {
            sendResponse(response);
        });
    }
});

function execute(data){
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject){

        /* ... */

        $.ajax(options).done(function(data) {
            return resolve(data);
        });
    });

}
```

What's the solution ?

I need to add onMessageListener in my contentscript and background, so, I don't use sendResponse ?

Thanks

Comment: Add `return true` inside `if` block in the listener: [Chrome Extension Message passing: response not sent](//stackoverflow.com/a/20077854)

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't find. Thanks.